# The impact on the deciphering of the Carian language on proto-Anatolian

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, anatolian

Despite written in an alphabetic script, the [Carian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carian_language) resisted decipherment for a long time and we can only read it for about three decades now. The Carian language turned out to be a member of the Luwian branch of the Anatolian languages.

What impact has the decipherment of the Carian language to our knowledge of the Anotolian languages, especially on the reconstruction of proto-Anatolian?